# How do I integrate a dll from an existing program into my c# windows application?

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to use the functionality of cygwin in my c# windows application and want to save the output according to user needs (my output files should be location independent). How do I do this?

I'm browsing my input file from cygwin folder and want to execute the cygwin command i.e. gcc main_jaxa.c sar-function.c nrutil.c complex16.c. Is it possible to execute this command through a windows application written in c#.net?

Then I want to call the a.exe file to convert my input files in to the output files.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String,String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx), which allows you to launch an arbitrary process with a set of command line parameters.